# DIfferentiability at a point for a mod plus floor function.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

$$f(x)=|x^2-4x+3|floor(x^2)$$
To understand this function better let's split this up into intervals in $[0,\sqrt{10})$ and analyse it.
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x\in[0,1)\\
-(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[1,\sqrt{2})\\
-2(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\\
-3(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[\sqrt{3},2)\\
-4(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[2,\sqrt{5})\\
-5(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[\sqrt{5},\sqrt{6})\\
-6(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[\sqrt{6},\sqrt{7})\\
-7(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[\sqrt{7},\sqrt{8})\\
-8(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[\sqrt{8},3)\\
 9(x-1)(x-3) & x\in[3,\sqrt{10})\\
\end{cases}$$
$$f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x\in(0,1)\\
-(2x-4) & x\in(1,\sqrt{2})\\
-2(2x-4) & x\in(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\\
-3(2x-4) & x\in(\sqrt{3},2)\\
-4(2x-4) & x\in(2,\sqrt{5})\\
-5(2x-4) & x\in(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{6})\\
-6(2x-4) & x\in(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{7})\\
-7(2x-4) & x\in(\sqrt{7},\sqrt{8})\\
-8(2x-4) & x\in(\sqrt{8},3)\\
 9(2x-4) & x\in(3,\sqrt{10})\\
\end{cases}$$
Clearly, $f'(2)$ does not exist since in the initial definition $f$ is discontinuous at 2. But this a removable point discontinuity.

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}f'(x)=0$

Can someone check and tell me if this analysis is correct?

Comment: I think it should be -9(x-1)(x-3) and -9(2x-4); besides the Floor has zero derivative at any integer value, not just 2. What is so especial about this point anyway? All the rest seems to be correct.

Comment: This was an homework question. It was like “ Discuss the continuity and differentiability of $f$ in the interval [0,4] “ This certain point was just a doubt that had arisen in my mind while solving this question. And I’m sure f is positive x>3